# Can someone explain what the primitives and parameters mean in my Graphics3D code?

Tags: graphics3d, list-manipulation, geometric-transform

```
Graphics3D[
  Table[
    GeometricTransformation[
      Cuboid[{1, 0, 0}, {.01, .2, .1}], 
      {RotationMatrix[a, {0, 0, .05}], {.001 Cos[a], .001 Sin[a], a}}], 
    {a, -Pi, 2 Pi, .2}], 
  Boxed -> False]
```

I followed this [Documentation Center page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) about rotating cuboids along a space curve to make the above code (which creates the stairs for spiral staircase). I don't want to just follow it, though, I would like to understand everything I am typing in. After researching the primitives, I know that `Cuboid[{a,b,c},{d,e,f}]` creates a cuboid with corner `{a, b, c}` and opposing corner `{d, e, f}`.

But other than that, I'm not all sure what else is going on. I can *guess* at what is going on, but that does not make me feel confident in my Mathematica usage.

Specific questions:

- What does `Table` do? When reading about it, I cannot make sense of why I need it in my code.
- `Graphics3D` creates a 3D image based upon the primitives and directives entered. Is this correct? What else should I know about this?
- To make sure I understand primitives and directives clearly: `Table` is a primitive for `Graphics3D`. `GeometricTransformation` is a primitive for `Table`. `Cuboid` and `RotationMatrix` are primitives for `GeometricTransformation`. `Boxed` is a directive for `Graphics3D`. And things like `{a, b, c}` are parameters for equations or primitives. Is this correct? Sorry, this may read like a riddle.
- Final questions: What exactly does `GeometricTransformation` do? Is it basically saying "I'd like to rotate something (a cuboid) about an axis and in the shape of a helix?" Where are the vectors/matrices coming to play in this? [This](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotationMatrix.html) is where I read about it, but it does not help me much in understanding what I am doing.

Comment: You can look up the functions in the docs. For example, Table is a very general command that has nothing to do with graphics. Put the cursor on the command and press F1.

Comment: When you try to understand code, reduce individual parts to as small as possible blocks. E.g., you'll understand Table, when you use it in a very simple form, such as Table[4,{5}], which will produce you a list of five 4 (just test it). So Table will produce a list with a certain number of elements. Then try some more complex stuff, e.g. Table[a+4,{a,1,5}], which will again produce a list with 5 elements, this time {5,6,7,8,9}. I'll guess you already figured out, why. Then take it the next step further, and so on.

Comment: It is designed to be more efficient with `GeometricTransformation` and `Table` transposed, as in the example in the docs.  Look at the 4th (last) synopsis at the top of the doc page: `GeometricTransformation[g, {t1, t2,...}]`.  (In the documentation example, `Table` makes the list of transformations `{t1, t2,...}`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your code produces a picture of a "spiral staircase", there are some choices of parameters the escape my understanding, so let's look at simplified version with some debugging code added.

```
Module[{t, g},
  g = Graphics3D[
    t = Table[
      GeometricTransformation[
        Cuboid[{1, 0, 0}, {.01, .2, .1}],
        {RotationMatrix[a, {0, 0, 1}],(* rotation by angle a about z-axis *)
         {0, 0, a} (* translation by a along z-axis *)}],
      {a, -Pi, 2 Pi, .2}],
    Boxed -> False];
 Print[Row[{"Number of cuboids: ", Length@t}]];
 g]
```

> ```
> Number of cuboids: 48
> ```

[image: staircase.png]

The `Table` expression produces 48 cuboids (the steps), each one slightly different from tho others because of the iteration variable `a` is stepped from -Pi to 2 Pi by step size 0.2. `GeometricTransformation` applies two geometric transforms to the cuboid as each table element is generated. These are a rotation about and a translation along the z-axis, which are given in its the second argument.

The number 48 comes from the iteration descriptor, `{a, -Pi, 2 Pi, .2}`, which calls for `Ceiling[(2 Pi - (-Pi))/.2]` steps (which evaluates to 48).

#### Edit

This is to satisfy the OP's request for more information on the role of `RotationMatrix`.

`GeometricTransformation` needs to told what transforms to use and its second argument supplies that info. In this case, it is given a list of two transforms, a rotation by angle `a` about the z-axis and a translation by `a` along the z-axis. Let `RotationMatrix[a, {0, 0, 1}]`, the first item in the list, be denoted by `r`. Then `r.{x, y, z}` gives `{x Cos[a] - y Sin[a], y Cos[a] + x Sin[a], z}`, the rotation of `{x, y, z}` by angle `a` about the z-axis.

Comment: Some of my parameters have to do with the other elements of the staircase that I left out of the question because I understand those functions (adequately, at least). I'm sure my parameters are a bit wacky, even considering the other factors the other functions bring in, but I'm just going for understanding right now. 

And, thank you very much! You answer has especially helped me understand the Table aspect. Do you know how the RotationMatrix come into play? I would think the GeometricTransformation would suffice for rotating the steps in the helical shape.

Comment: I think I get the gist of everything going on here now. Thank you so very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you indent the code, it's easier to see its structure

```
Graphics3D[
    Table[
        GeometricTransformation[
            Cuboid[{1, 0, 0}, {.01, .2, .1}],
            {RotationMatrix[ a, {0, 0, .05}], {.001 Cos[a], .001 Sin[a], a}}],
    {a, -[Pi], 2 Pi, .2}
    ], Boxed -> False
]
```

`Graphics3D` is a container for three-dimensional graphics objects, like `Cuboid`.
`Table` is used here to produce a list of transformed cuboids depending on parameter `a`. Consider it an iteration construct that stores each step in a list (that will be passed to `Graphics3D` to be shown).
`GeometricTransformation` takes a graphics object and produce another graphics object that has been transformed according to the specified transformation rule, here a rototranslation (if I am not mistaken).

I have not run the code, but I believe it will generate a series of pictures of a rolling cuboid. Well, sort of... Er, let's say it's 'spirolling'.

Comment: thanks for both the edit and the response! It was very informative.